# Passing child nodes from mounting point to react element

Tags: reactjs, children, child-nodes

We have 2 large existing web sites that we need to share UI components between. The plan is that these components are lazy loaded and can be mounted anywhere in the page as often as required by writing a div tag with a data attributes for the props e.g

```
<div data-component="InfoNotification" data-title="Example InfoNotification">
    <p>With child elements</p>
</div>
```

So this HTML above should mount an InfoNotification component to the page and pass it `props.title` of "Example notification" and `props.children` of `<p>With child elements</p>`

This works except for the child nodes are not getting through to `props.children` for some reason.

Lazy loading logic:

```
import AL from './AsyncLoadable'
asyncComponents.InfoNotification = AL({loader: () => import('./lib/notifications/InfoNotification.jsx')})
```

Component mounting code:

```
import { asyncComponents } from './registeredAsyncComponents'

// Find any react mounting points on the page and load the correct component for them
const mountPoints = document.querySelectorAll('div[data-component],span[data-component]')
for (let i = 0; i < mountPoints.length; i++) {
    if (asyncComponents[mountPoints[i].dataset.component]) {
        let children = mountPoints[i].childNodes; // <-- if this was a react element it would work
        let loadableComponent = React.createElement(asyncComponents[mountPoints[i].dataset.component], mountPoints[i].dataset, children)
        ReactDOM.render(
            <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
                {loadableComponent}
            </I18nextProvider>,
            mountPoints[i]
        )
    } else {
        console.error(`Unable to find a registered component named ${mountPoints[i].dataset.component}. Please register async components in src/registeredAsyncComponents.js`)
    }
}
```

The InfoNotification component works correctly through react, just not when trying to pass the DOM nodes into the react children property.

Note: We have corporate customers and an IE11 compatible solution is required

Comment: It seems to be a problem with me passing DOM elements as children and not react elements. If I replace `let children = mountPoints[i].childNodes` with `let children = (<div>test</div>)` the children are passed correctly. How can I create react elements from DOM elements?